# How to close and delete a file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, file

Say that I open a file in Ruby like this:

```
f = File.open('diagram.txt', 'r')
```

Right now, in order to close and delete that file I have this code:

```
begin
  f = File.open('diagram.txt', 'r')
ensure
  if !f.nil? && File.exist?(f)
    f.close unless f.closed? 
    File.delete(f)
  end
end
```

I found this code to be too complicated, and the `File.exist?(f)` would fail if the f is closed already. So, what is the correct approach to avoid the closing and deleting of the file raising exceptions?

Note: I know that passing a block to File.open will close the file directly, however, I am looking for the general approach of closing and deleting.

Comment: If you pass a block to File.open, it will automatically close the file at the end of the block.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Handling the Errno::ENOENT Exception

Since your *diagram.txt* file is not guaranteed to exist in your example code, your bigger problem is handling the **Errno::ENOENT** exception. You can Call [File#open](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/File.html#method-c-open) in a self-closing block, and then use rescue to handle the exception if you try to open or delete a missing file. For example:

```ruby
begin
  File.open('diagram.txt', 'r') do |f|
    # do something with file
    File.delete(f)
  end
rescue Errno::ENOENT
end
```

Comment: @konsolebox Then you'll probably get Errno::EACCES (at least on Linux), but that's a separate question outside the scope of the OP's original question. Adapt your rescue as necessary, or open a new question.

Comment: What I actually mean is if the file is not readable, but the OP still needs to delete the file, the file won't get deleted since EACCESS would be thrown.

Answer (score 14):

Why not just delete the file after closing and not depending from the object but from the filename itself?

```
begin
  f = File.open('diagram.txt', 'r')
ensure
  f.close unless f.nil? or f.closed?
  File.delete('diagram.txt') if File.exists? 'diagram.txt'
end
```

Comment: File.exists? is deprecated you can use File.exist?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your specific situation, it might be possible to use [`Tempfile.create`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html#method-c-create). From [the docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html#method-c-create):

> If a block is given, then a File object will be constructed, and the block is invoked with the object as the argument. **The File object will be automatically closed and the temporally file is removed after the block terminates.** The call returns the value of the block.

(Emphasis mine)

Usage:

```
require 'tempfile'

Tempfile.create('diagram.txt') do |f|
  # Do something with the file
end
```